# Putting a Border Around Floating Elements

Tags: css, border, css-float

Say I have something like the following code, where I want to display some text between two images that I am floating left and right.

```
<img src="testImage1.png" alt="Test Image 1" style="float:right;" />
<img src="testImage2.png" alt="Test Image 2" style="float:left;" />
<p>Test Text</p>
```

I want to add a border around the two images and the text. I tried putting a `<div>` around all 3 of the above tags and using `style="border:2px black solid;"`. While this adds a border, it seems to not take the images into account. That is, we get something like the following (using StackOverflow and Google logos).

[image]

I am guessing this is happening because the floating elements are not being considered as part of the `<div>`. I am a software developer, not a web developer, so I am no expert in CSS. But I do think I recall that floating elements are kind of "ignored" in a way. Can anyone give a detailed description of what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: you can try.     outline: 2px solid blue;

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Adding an `overflow` in this case with a value of `hidden` or `auto` remedies the issue.

Check the fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/XMrwR/

> ***Clearing floats the overflow way***
>
> http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/03/clearing_floats.html

Comment: Cool. So basically add `overflow:hidden;` to the `<div>`. It worked. Thanks. +1.

Comment: I will mark it as the answer when it lets me. Says 10 minutes.

Answer (score 14):

In CSS, floated elements do not add height to a parent by default.

The solution is simply to set `overflow: hidden`.

```
<div style="border: 2px solid black; overflow: hidden;" 
    <img src="testImage1.png" alt="Test Image 1" style="float:right;" />
    <img src="testImage2.png" alt="Test Image 2" style="float:left;" />
    <p>Test Text</p>
</div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JNets/

Answer (score 7):

Add this line to your CSS properties:

```
overflow: hidden
```