# Border casuses overflow

Tags: html

I have built a header and I defined the width to 33.33%. This works fine as long as I don't have a border. As soon as I add the border it my right element will be displayed on the next line. Is there an attribute that collaborates with borders?

Comment: kindly post your code

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721001/putting-a-border-around-floating-elements) will help I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Given the standard **CSS Box Model** (*content-box*), your element's overall horizontal width will be:

`border-left` + `padding-left` + `width` + `padding-right` + `border-right`

As you can see, the `width` only refers to the width of the content - it doesn't include the padding or the borders.

Consequently, if your element is `33.33%` wide  and then you apply:

```
border: 2px solid rgb(0,0,0);
```

your element is *no longer* `33.33%` wide.

Now it's `2px` + `33.33%` + `2px` wide.

---

**Solution #1 using calc():**

You can continue referring to the standard **CSS Box Model** (*content-box*) but to compensate for the `2px` width border on each side, you can declare the element's width as:

```
width: calc(33.33% - 4px);
```

---

**Solution #2 using box-sizing:**

You can tell the browser not to refer to the standard **CSS Box Model** (*content-box*) and to use the alternative **CSS Box Model** (*border-box*) instead:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

When the browser refers to the *border-box* model, the `width` *does* include the content and the padding and the borders.

Comment: Why give the worse method first?

Comment: Because it accommodates the CSS Box Model which became the standard (ie. content-box). The contest over which Box Model should be the standard goes back to the Browser Wars of the mid-2000s. Border-Box was Internet Explorer's preferred implementation. There's (of course) nothing wrong with referring to the border-box model, but it's definitely also worth knowing how to approach this situation while continuing to refer to the content-box model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

> The width and height properties include the content, the padding and border, but not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer when the document is in Quirks mode. Note that padding and border will be inside of the box e.g.  .box {width: 350px; border: 10px solid black;} leads to a box rendered in the browser of width: 350px. The content box can't be negative and is floored to 0, making it impossible to use border-box to make the element disappear.
>       Here the dimension is calculated as, width = border + padding + width of the content, and height = border + padding + height of the content.

Comment: @Quentin thanks I was trying to fix the blockquote but having trouble with it